# SQL Error near the word 'go'

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

Why does SQL Server report that this statement isn't correct?

```
use DIGITECH
go

select * 
from kunde as k
left join adresse as a on k.FK_AdID = a.AdID
where Name = 'Dirk'
go
```

SQL displays this error (in German):

> Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 14
>   Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von 'go'.
>
> Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 14
>   Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von 'go'.

Translated to english:

> Msg 102 , Level 15 , State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'go' .
>
> Msg 102 , Level 15 , State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'go' .

Comment: Its referring to the second go, not the first one. It could be anything  in the select statement. Add the alias to Name in the where clause

Comment: no, the where clause works fine. I think its something else

Comment: You might try a semicolon at the end of the SQL statement (after `'Dirk'`).

Comment: @GordonLinoff isn't work sorry

Comment: @GordonLinoff when I double click on the message I jump the first line of the select Statement

Comment: To isolate the issue, just copy out the select on to a new page and run it. I don't see anything wrong with what you've got so this is probably one of those issues where there's something you've forgotten to tell us or something we can't see

Comment: ... in fact your script has 8 lines but the error is on line 14 so there's definitely something you're not telling us.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yea but this are only some commands ....

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I copyed the Statement out but it insnt work

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when I delete all "go" in my script, then its work fine

Comment: OK so I'm guessing there is nothing wrong with the script you have posted and the problem is in some part of the script you haven't posted. Why don't you post the full script, including line 14

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I found the mistake, i needed to delete all "go". And then its work... I have other scripts and there works with the go Statement fine .. I love SQL -.-

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you for your help +rep

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid this one for example:
select bes.OrderID, pro.Produktname, k.Name, k.Vorname, bes.Status from kunde as k
 join bestellung as bes
  on k.KID = bes.FK_KID
 join verbindungstabelle_produkt_order as ver
  on bes.OrderID = ver.FK_OrderID
 join produkt as pro
  on ver.FK_PID = pro.PID
where bes.Status = 'bestellt'
go
I hope you can read it

Comment: I suggest that if you have a problem with your script you edit your question and post the _entire_ script not just bits of it. There's nothing wrong the bits and pieces you are posting. Edit your post and add the entire script including line 14

Comment: `GO` is **not** a SQL statement - it's a *separator* used by Management Studio to separate SQL blocks. If you execute this SQL from e.g. your C# code, then you **cannot** use the `GO` separator keyword

Comment: Try the standard `;` delimiter instead of `GO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have pointed out, `GO` is the default batch delimiter for tools like Management Studio or sqlcmd. SQL Server does not understand `GO`, the tools use it to separate batches and send individual batches to SQL Server. You probably took an entire .sql file and executed in your app.

You can use a library like [DbUtilSqlCmd](https://github.com/rusanu/com.rusanu.dbutil) which understands the sqlcmd delimiters (`GO`), and other sqlcmd specific syntax like `:setvar`, and execute your .sql file through it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the database in the query and avoid the `go` statements?  For example:

```
select * from DIGITECH.dbo.kunde as k
    left join DIGITECH.dbo.adresse as a
        on k.FK_AdID = a.AdID
    where Name = 'Dirk'
```

Comment: this is not the mistake but thank you for your answer

Comment: It seems to be that another possibility is that you need to have a blank line after the last `go` at the end of the script.